# No redirect on signout from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, logout

Signing out from my rails app generates an error of `Completed 204 No Content` in the log.  The view just freezes until manually refreshed.

I have tracked the error to the way the DELETE request is handled:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-09 06:55:24 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as */*
```

The second line should have `HTML` instead of `*/*`.  Any tips on what configuration I need to change to fix that?

UPDATE
This is a test app using Rails backend and the HyperReact modules from the Hyperloop project.  So the view is rendered as a React component.  Here is the code for that component:

```
module Components
  module Users
    class Show < React::Component::Base
      param :name, type: String
      param :provider, type: String
      param :signed_in_at, type: String
      param :ip, type: String
      param :avatar, type: String

      def render
        div do
          img(src: params.avatar, width: 50, height: 50)
          h1 { "Hello and welcome to your profile page #{params.name}!"}
          h2 { "You are signed in with #{params.provider} since #{params.signed_in_at}." }
          h3 { "Your ip is #{params.ip}." }
          button.btn.btn_default(type: :button) { "Signout!" }.on(:click) do
            HTTP.delete("users/sign_out")
            alert("Signing out")
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post how you're signing out? The code of the link / button that you're using? From the looks of it that's your issue.

Comment: @Mark updated with signout code.

Comment: the code seems to be fine, did you define a root_path? devise use this for basic redirects after interactions, since is saying "no content" i guess it doesn't have where to go, if there is another problem you could always overwrite the after_sign_out_path method(or something like that, not sure about the name, but is in the devise wiki)

Comment: In routes.rb root is set to `users#show` but the users_controller has a `before_action :authenticate_user!` at the top.  If not authenticated, it should use the Devise users::sessions controller, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in your case my answer does not make sense. For devise it is usually necessary to define the :method=>"delete" as well. I see that you do that but I am not sure if the link is correct anyways. 
The usual sign out link in rails looks like

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

What happens if you use `.destroy` instead of `delete` ? as the action is called 'destroy' and the http method delete. I am sorry however, I am not familiar with that syntax you are showing.

Comment: I have almost zero javascript knowledge, so bear with me.  Would I put `remote: true` above the `HTTP.delete` call?  And the devise `#destroy` method is: 

`DELETE /resource/sign_out`
      `def destroy`
        `super`
      `end`

Sorry for the formatting issues.

Comment: My understanding is that HTTP.delete is the equivalent of the `:method => :delete` call in an erb file.  I did try various permutations of including `method: delete` calls that would not even lead to a signout at all.  Unless my understanding is incorrect, the route for `users/sign_out` should trigger the Devise Users::Sessions controller to use the #destroy method.